Why won't my CSS variables change value?
I'm making changes to Atum.
I'm changing the colours and I'm using user.css.  I've placed it in:
 /media/templates/administrator/atum/css/user.css
I initially tried using :root and giving each variable a HEX value which worked.
I then decided it would be more efficient to assign the original variables with a new variable.  That way if I wanted to I could restyle things in the future with a more descriptive way of knowing what each colour does.
When I try to reassign the variable such as:
--header-logo-bg: var(--blue--400);
I lose all colours.

So then I thought I would try to localise the rule by targeting body instead.
body {
  /* Square Balloon Brand Colours */
  --blue--900: #2d3945;
  --blue--800: #233a5a;
  --blue--700: #54667f;
  --blue--600: #046b8d;
  --blue--400: #00aeff 
  --blue--200: #c3e7f3;

  --pink--200: #fee0dd;
  --pink--500: #f04c5e;
  --pink--600: #d51d4f;

  --yellow--800: #ee5d23;
  --yellow--700: #f9a41e;
  --yellow--400: #f5df99;
  --yellow--300: #f5e7c4;

  
  --header-logo-bg: var(--blue--400);
  --header-bg: var(--blue--400);
  --sidebarwrapper-bg: var(--blue--400);
  --main-nav-mm-active-bg: var(--blue--900);
  --template-sidebar-bg: var(--blue--400);
  --btn-primary-bg: var(--blue--400);
  --btn-secondary-border: var(--blue--200: #c3e7f3);
  --btn-secondary-color: #fff;
  --btn-secondary-bg: var(--blue--400);
  --btn-secondary-border: var(--blue--900);
  --header-item-content-bg: var(--blue--900);
  --header-item-content-jversion-color: var(--blue--900);
  -main-nav-ul-bg: var(--blue--900);
}

This also does not work.  However if I just use the colour hex's instead of the variables it works fine.
What could I be doing wrong?

There's a missing semi-colon.  Twat.  All solved.
Thanks ChatGPT, you're a great friend.
Also a duplicate rule.  Good catch CGPT.
Full code
There's a missing semi-colon.  Twat.  All solved.
  --blue--600: #046b8d;
  --blue--400: #00aeff   <<<<<<
  --blue--200: #c3e7f3;

Thanks ChatGPT, you're a great friend.
Also a duplicate rule.  Good catch Chat GPT.
  --btn-secondary-border: var(--blue--200: #c3e7f3); <<<<<
  --btn-secondary-color: #fff;
  --btn-secondary-bg: var(--blue--400);
  --btn-secondary-border: var(--blue--900);  <<<<

Full code
body {
  /* Square Balloon Brand Colours */
  --blue--900: #2d3945;
  --blue--800: #233a5a;
  --blue--700: #54667f;
  --blue--600: #046b8d;
  --blue--400: #00aeff:
  --blue--200: #c3e7f3;

  --pink--600: #d51d4f;
  --pink--500: #f04c5e;
  --pink--200: #fee0dd;

  --yellow--800: #ee5d23;
  --yellow--700: #f9a41e;
  --yellow--400: #f5df99;
  --yellow--300: #f5e7c4;

  
  --header-logo-bg: var(--blue--400);
  --header-bg: var(--blue--400);
  --sidebarwrapper-bg: var(--blue--400);
  --main-nav-mm-active-bg: var(--blue--900);
  --template-sidebar-bg: var(--blue--400);
  --btn-primary-bg: var(--blue--400);
  --btn-secondary-border: var(--blue--900);
  --btn-secondary-color: #fff;
  --btn-secondary-bg: var(--blue--400);
  --header-item-content-bg: var(--blue--900);
  --header-item-content-jversion-color: var(--blue--900);
  -main-nav-ul-bg: var(--blue--900);
}


What was the correct syntax with the colon that you used? Could you include it in your answer for people who may find this in the future.
